# Variable input python -Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a GUI in Tkinter( tennisGUI) which is meant to get "user input" and gives another python scripts(tennisTotal.py) "output.

Everything works except 1 thing I just can't get to work. How to get the "user input" in the other script(tennisTotal.py.

For example, in the GUI there is a field "Service stats Serving player". I want the input from this field into the "tennisTotal.py" script

Any comments and suggestions on the script are also welcome as I'm rather new on pythong.

> tennisGUI script

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\Tennis\tennisTotal.py")


class App(Frame):
    def run_script(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        try:
            del(sys.modules["tennisTotal"])
        except:
            # Yeah, it's a real ugly solution...
            pass
        import tennisTotal
        tennisTotal
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

    def build_widgets(self):
        self.text1 = Text(self, height=8, width=25, font=('time', 9, 'italic'))
        self.text1.grid(row=13, column=6, columnspan=2, rowspan=50, padx=10, pady=10)

        Label(self, text="Players & Stats", font="Verdana 10 bold").grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(self, text="Serving Player").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Receiving Player").grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Scoring", font="Verdana 10 bold").grid(row=13, column=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(self, text="Game Score Serving Player").grid(row=14, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Game Score Receiving Player").grid(row=15, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Set Score Serving Player").grid(row=16, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Set Score Receiving Player").grid(row=17, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Stats", font="Verdana 10 bold").grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=3)
        Label(self, text="Service stats Serving Player").grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Service stats Receiving Player").grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Return stats Serving Player").grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='w')
        Label(self, text="Return stats Receiving Player").grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='w')

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e2 = Entry(self)
        e3 = Entry(self)
        e4 = Entry(self)
        e5 = Entry(self)
        e6 = Entry(self)
        e7 = Entry(self)
        e8 = Entry(self)
        e9 = Entry(self)
        e10 = Entry(self)

        e1.insert(10, "Novak Djokovic")
        e2.insert(10, "Andy Murray")
        e3.insert(10, "30")
        e4.insert(10, "15")
        e5.insert(10, "2")
        e6.insert(10, "1")
        e7.insert(10, "75.2%")
        e8.insert(10, "72.2%")
        e9.insert(10, "30.5%")
        e10.insert(10, "27.5%")

        e1.grid(row=2, column=4)
        e2.grid(row=3, column=4)
        e3.grid(row=14, column=4, padx=10)
        e4.grid(row=15, column=4)
        e5.grid(row=16, column=4)
        e6.grid(row=17, column=4)
        e7.grid(row=5, column=4)
        e8.grid(row=6, column=4)
        e9.grid(row=7, column=4)
        e10.grid(row=8, column=4)

        Button(self, text='Run', command=self.run_script).grid(row=12, column=2, columnspan=6, ipadx=100, pady=15)

    def write(self, txt):
        self.text1.insert(INSERT, txt)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.build_widgets()


root = Tk()
app = App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

> tennisTotal script --> The first 11 lines is where I want al the "user input" form the tennisGUI script.

```
s_point=0.6
v_game_point=0
w_game_point=0
v_tiebreak=0
w_tiebreak=0
returnpoint_server=0.3
v_games_in_set=0
w_games_in_set=0
v_sets_won=0
w_sets_won=0
best_of=5


def fact(x):
    if x in[0, 1]:
        return 1
    r = 1
    for a in range(1, (x+1)):
        r = r*a
    return r


def ch(a, b):
    return fact(a)/(fact(b)*fact(a-b))


def gameOutcome(s, a, b):
    return ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)*s

# Game Probability
def gameProb(s=s_point, v=v_game_point, w=w_game_point):
    # function calculates the probability of server winning
    # a single game, given p(winning any given point) [s],
    # and the current point score.
    # v, w = current game score, where love = 0, 15 = 1, etc.
    # - e.g. 30-15 is v=2, w=1
    # check if game is already over:
    if v >= 4 and (v-w) >= 2:
        return 1
    elif w >= 4 and (w-v) >= 2:
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    # if deuce or ad score e.g. 5-4, reduce to e.g. 3-2
    while True:
        if (v+w) > 6:
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:
            break
    # specific probabilities:
    if w == 0:
        w0 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 0)
    else:
        w0 = 0
    if w <= 1:
        w15 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 1-w)
    else:
        w15 = 0
    if w <= 2:
        w30 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 2-w)
    else:
        w30 = 0
    if v == 4:
        wAd, lAd = s, 0
        d = 1-s
    elif w == 4:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 1-s
        d = s
    else:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 0
        a = 3 - v
        b = 3 - w
        d = ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)
    if v <= 2:
        l30 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 2-v)
    else:
        l30 = 0
    if v <= 1:
        l15 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 1-v)
    else:
        l15 = 0
    if v == 0:
        l0 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 0)
    else:
        l0 = 0
    # given d = prob of getting to deuce,
    # math to divide up further outcomes
    denom = s**2 + (1-s)**2
    wd = (d*(s**2))/denom
    ld = (d*((1-s)**2))/denom
    win = w0 + w15 + w30 + wd + wAd
    lose = l0 + l15 + l30 + ld + lAd
    return win

# Tiebreak Probability
def tiebreakProb(s=s_point, t=returnpoint_server, v=v_tiebreak, w=w_tiebreak, p=7):
    # calculate the probability that the current server wins a best-of-p
    # tiebreak.
    # s = p(server wins service point)
    # t = p(current server wins return point)
    # v, w = current score
    # check if tiebreak is already over:
    if v >= p and (v-w) >= 2:
        return 1
    elif w >= p and (w-v) >= 2:
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    # re-adjust so that point score is not higher than p;
    # e.g., if p=7 and score is 8-8, adjust to 6-6, which
    # is logically equivalent
    while True:
        if (v+w) > 2*(p-1):
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:
            break
    outcomes = {}
    # track probability of each possible score
    # this is messy and probably not optimal, figuring out
    # how many points remain, and how many are on each
    # player's serve:
    for i in range((p-1)):
        remain = p + i - v - w
        if remain < 1:
            continue
        else:
            pass
        if remain % 2 == 1:
            if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
                if (remain-1) % 4 == 0:
                    svc = (remain+1)/2
                    ret = (remain-1)/2
                else:
                    svc = (remain-1)/2
                    ret = (remain+1)/2
            else:
                if (remain-1) % 4 == 0:
                    svc = (remain+1)/2
                    ret = (remain-1)/2
                else:
                    svc = (remain+1)/2
                    ret = (remain-1)/2
        else:
            if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
                    svc, ret = remain/2, remain/2
            else:
                svc, ret = (remain-2)/2, (remain-2)/2
                if remain % 4 == 0:
                    svc += 1
                    ret += 1
                else:
                    svc += 2
        # who serves the last point?
        if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
            if (remain % 4) in [0, 1]:
                final = s
                svc -= 1
            else:
                final = t
                ret -= 1
        else:
            if (remain % 4) in [3, 0]:
                final = t
                ret -= 1
            else:
                final = s
                svc -= 1
        pOutcome = 0
        for j in range(svc+1):
            for k in range(ret+1):
                if (j+k) == (p - 1 - v):
                    m = svc - j
                    n = ret - k
                    pr = (s**j)*(t**k)*((1-s)**m)*((1-t)**n)*ch(svc, j)*ch(ret, k)*final
                    pOutcome += pr
                else:
                    continue
        key = str(p) + str(i)
        outcomes[key] = pOutcome
    if remain % 2 == 1:
        if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
            if (remain-1) % 4 == 0:
                svc = (remain+1)/2
                ret = (remain-1)/2
            else:
                svc = (remain-1)/2
                ret = (remain+1)/2
        else:
            if (remain-1) % 4 == 0:
                svc = (remain+1)/2
                ret = (remain-1)/2
            else:
                svc = (remain+1)/2
                ret = (remain-1)/2
    else:
        if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
            svc, ret = remain/2, remain/2
        else:
            svc, ret = (remain-2)/2, (remain-2)/2
            if remain % 4 == 0:
                svc += 1
                ret += 1
            else:
                svc += 2
    # probability of getting to (p-1)-(p-1) (e.g. 6-6)
    final = 1
    x = 0
    for j in range(svc+1):
        for k in range(ret+1):
            if (j+k) == (p - 1 - v):
                m = svc - j
                n = ret - k
                pr = (s**j)*(t**k)*((1-s)**m)*((1-t)**n)*ch(svc, j)*ch(ret, k)*final
                x += pr
            else:
                continue
    outcomes['+'] = (x*s*t)/((s*t) + (1-s)*(1-t))
    # add up all positive outcomes
    wtb = 0
    for z in outcomes:
        wtb += outcomes[z]
    return wtb

# Set Probability
def setOutcome(final, sGames, rGames, vw, g, h):
    pOutcome = 0
    for j in range((sGames+1)):
        for k in range((rGames+1)):
            if (j + k) == (6 - 1 - vw):
                m = sGames - j
                n = rGames - k
                p = (g**j)*(h**k)*((1-g)**m)*((1-h)**n)*ch(sGames, j)*ch(rGames, k)*final
                pOutcome += p
            else:
                continue
    return pOutcome


def setGeneral(s=s_point, u=returnpoint_server, v=v_games_in_set, w=w_games_in_set, tb=1):
    # calculate the probability of the current server winning
    # a 6-game, tiebreak set, given prob. of server winning any
    # given service point (s) or return point (u), and the current
    # game score (v, w)
    # get prob of current server winning a service game:
    g = gameProb(s)
    # and current server winning a return game:
    h = gameProb(u)
    # is set over?
    if tb:
        if v == 7:
            return 1
        elif w == 7:
            return 0
        elif v == 6 and (v-w) > 1:
            return 1
        elif w == 6 and (w-v) > 1:
            return 0
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if v >= 6 and (v-w) > 1:
            return 1
        elif w >= 6 and (w-v) > 1:
            return 0
        else:
            pass
    # if not over, re-adjust down to no higher than 6-6
    while True:
        if (v+w) > 12:
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:
            break
    # if no tiebreak, chance that server wins set is ratio
    # of server's prob of winning
    # two games in a row to returner's prob of winning two games in a row
    if not tb:
        deuceprob = (g*h)/((g*h) + (1-g)*(1-h))
    outcomes = {}
    # special cases, 11 games or more already
    if (v+w) == 12:
        if tb:
            tp = tiebreakProb(s, u)
            outcomes['76'] = tp
            outcomes['67'] = 1 - tp
        else:
            outcomes['75'] = deuceprob
            outcomes['57'] = 1-deuceprob
    elif (v+w) == 11:
        if tb:
            tp = tiebreakProb((1-u), (1-s))
            if v == 6:
                outcomes['75'] = g
                x = (1-g)
                outcomes['76'] = x*(1 - tp)
                outcomes['67'] = x*tp
            else:
                outcomes['57'] = 1-g
                x = g
                outcomes['76'] = x*(1 - tp)
                outcomes['67'] = x*tp
        else:
            if v == 6:
                outcomes['75'] = g
                outcomes['57'] = 0
                f = 1 - g
            else:
                outcomes['57'] = 1-g
                outcomes['75'] = 0
                f = g
            outcomes['75'] += f*deuceprob
            outcomes['57'] += f*(1-deuceprob)
    else:
        for i in range(5):
            t = 6 + i - v - w
            if t < 1:
                continue
            if t % 2 == 0:
                final = h
                sGames = t/2
                rGames = sGames - 1
            else:
                final = g
                sGames = (t-1)/2
                rGames = (t-1)/2
            pOutcome = setOutcome(final, sGames, rGames, v, g, h)
            key = '6' + str(i)
            outcomes[key] = pOutcome
        # loss probabilities
        # this section isn't necessary, but I wrote it for informal
        # testing purposes
        for i in range(5):
            t = 6 + i - v - w
            if t < 1:
                continue
            if t % 2 == 0:
                final = 1-h
                sGames = t/2
                rGames = sGames - 1
            else:
                final = 1-g
                sGames = (t-1)/2
                rGames = (t-1)/2
            pOutcome = setOutcome(final, sGames, rGames, w, (1-g), (1-h))
            key = str(i) + '6'
            outcomes[key] = pOutcome
        t = 10 - v - w
        if t % 2 == 0:
            sGames = t/2
            rGames = t/2
        else:
            sGames = (t-1)/2 + 1
            rGames = (t-1)/2
        f = setOutcome(1, sGames, rGames, v, g, h)
        if tb == 1:
            outcomes['75'] = f*g*h
            outcomes['57'] = f*(1-g)*(1-h)
            x = f*g*(1-h) + f*(1-g)*h
            if (v+w) % 2 == 0:
                tp = tiebreakProb(s, u)
            else:
                tp = tiebreakProb(u, s)
            outcomes['76'] = x*tp
            outcomes['67'] = x - x*tp
        else:
            outcomes['75'] = f*deuceprob
            outcomes['57'] = f*(1-deuceprob)
    win = 0
    for o in outcomes:
        if o in ['60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '75', '76']:
            win += outcomes[o]
        else:
            pass
    return win

#Match Probability
def matchGeneral(e, v=0, w=0, s=3):
    # calculates probability of winning the match
    # from the beginning of a set
    # e is p(winning a set)
    # v and w is current set score
    # s is total number of sets ("best of")
    towin = (s+1)/2
    left = towin - v
    if left == 0:
        return 1
    remain = s - v - w
    if left > remain:
        return 0
    win = 0
    for i in range(left, (remain+1)):
        add = ch((i-1), (left-1))*(e**(left-1))*((1-e)**(i-left))*e
        win += add
    return win


def matchProb(s=s_point, t=returnpoint_server, gv=v_game_point, gw=w_game_point, sv=v_games_in_set, sw=w_games_in_set, mv=v_sets_won, mw=w_sets_won, sets=best_of):
    # calculates probability of winning a match from any given score,
    # given:
    # s, t: p(server wins a service point), p(server wins return point)
    # gv, gw: current score within the game. e.g. 30-15 is 2, 1
    # sv, sw: current score within the set. e.g. 5, 4
    # mv, mw: current score within the match (number of sets for each player)
    # v's are serving player; w's are returning player
    # sets: "best of", so default is best of 3
    a = gameProb(s)
    b = gameProb(t)
    c = setGeneral(s, t)
    if gv == 0 and gw == 0:
        if sv == 0 and sw == 0:
            return matchGeneral(c, v=mv, w=mw, s=sets)
        else:
            sWin = setGeneral(a, b, s, t, v=sv, w=sw)
            sLoss = 1 - sWin
    elif sv == 6 and sw == 6:
        sWin = tiebreakProb(s, t, v=gv, w=gw)
        sLoss = 1 - sWin
    else:
        gWin = gameProb(s, v=gv, w=gw)
        gLoss = 1 - gWin
        sWin = gWin*(1 - setGeneral((1-b), (1-a), (1-t), (1-s), v=sw, w=(sv+1)))
        sWin += gLoss*(1 - setGeneral((1-b), (1-a), (1-t), (1-s), v=(sw+1), w=sv))
        sLoss = 1 - sWin
    mWin = sWin*matchGeneral(c, v=(mv+1), w=mw, s=sets)
    mWin += sLoss*matchGeneral(c, v=mv, w=(mw+1), s=sets)
    return mWin, sLoss
print "Server Game = ""{0:.2%}".format(gameProb())
print "Receiver Game = ""{0:.2%}".format(1-gameProb())
print "Server Tiebreak = ""{0:.2%}".format(tiebreakProb())
print "Receiver Tiebreak = ""{0:.2%}".format(1-tiebreakProb())
print "Server Set = ""{0:.2%}".format(setGeneral())
print "Receiver Set = ""{0:.2%}".format(1-setGeneral())
print "Server Match = ""{0:.2%}".format(matchProb())
print "Receiver Match= ""{0:.2%}".format(1-matchProb())
```

Comment: I super don't recommend putting your script on the PATH. Just create a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: @erip, thanks for the advise. Could you also give me feedback on my question? Thx

Comment: It sounds like `tennisTotal` describes more a class then a module, I'd recommend just writing those functions that use global variables to be methods on something with instance variables.

Comment: @Tadhg so you recommend putting everything in 1 script? But how do I go about the variable input?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be one script, looking at it again it might be just as easy to make those print statements part of a `main` function that takes all the needed values as arguments.

Comment: I still don't understand how you expect to use the input from the user, you don't even keep a reference to the entries.  Hardcoding the variables and then using them as the function defaults and running them at module level really doesn't allow any room for dynamic modification though so any solution will require changes to tennisTotal for sure.

Comment: @Tadhg, thats why I've posted my question. Want know how to get the user input from the GUI in the first 11 lines of the tennisTotal script. The first 11 lines of the tennisTotal script are variable